# unable to map application to specific URL using Haproxy?

Tags: haproxy

I want to map an application called "page-designer" listening at http://206.189.22.155:5000 to the URL http://206.189.22.155/page-designer. Currently I have added the necessary configrations for the front end and backend in the main config file of haproxy.This config is valid but hitting the URL http://206.189.22.155/page-designer gives me a ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

haproxy.cfg

```
global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin expose-fd listeners
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
        # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
        #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
        # An alternative list with additional directives can be obtained from
        #  https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/?server=haproxy
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend fe_default
    bind 0.0.0.0:80
    mode http
    acl pagedesigner path_beg -i /page-designer

    use_backend bk_pagedesigner if pagedesigner

backend bk_pagedesigner
    server appserver1 1.2.3.4:5000
    mode http
```

Can someone point out what changes i have to make to this config file in order to succesfully map the running app to http://206.189.22.155/page-designer

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, you're not accepting HTTP connections.

You're only binding to :443 so for http:// (that is, :80), ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED seems about right if you have no other web server on the host.

The weird part is you're actually expecting HTTP over :443 with that configuration, and hitting http://206.189.22.155:443/data-core confirms that (by the way, thanks for not redacting this ).

You need to add an `ssl crt` directive to your bind option to properly terminate TLS using HAProxy, or bind to :80 instead.

Comment: hi i have updated my code

Comment: i changed the bind to :80 instead of 443.But now hitting http://206.189.22.155/page-designer is giving me 503 Service Unavailable.No server is available to handle this request.

Comment: and right now i want to do this using http instead of ssl

Comment: kindly plz help!!

Comment: If this is quite literally your configuration, I highly doubt you own 1.2.3.4 as an IP for your backend...

Comment: actually i changed that to server appserver1  206.189.22.155:5000

Comment: but now hitting 206.189.22.155/page-designer is showing cannot GET /page-designer

Comment: i tried this with another app running on port 30000(tomcat homepage).And that time hitting 206.189.22.155/page-designer is showing me http status 404 could not get requested resource

Comment: do we have to do this using http request redirect or set path?

Comment: if so can you show me an example using my configuration?

Comment: http://206.189.22.155:5000/ has no service listening on it so HAProxy sending a 500 error is pretty standard.